# Script for Mouseover to let GIF finish before Mouseout GIF can begin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I have two play-once GIFs similar to the ones attached.  I'd like to have the first GIF replace the original PNG upon mouseover, but even if someone removes the cursor from the image, finish playing the GIF so the last frame is in place before the mouseout GIF, which is the reverse of the previous one, replaces it and plays.  I'd also like the original PNG to replace the mouseout GIF when it is finished playing, too.  So, original > mouseover long enough to finish playing > mouseout long enough to finish playing > original.

I tried a javascript I found on here, and it worked to replace the images, but the mouseover GIF kept playing every now and again (even while the cursor was still on it) even though it is a play-once GIF (the script must have kept refreshing the GIF or something).

I'd keep the script in an external file as opposed to inline, of course.  I know enough javascript to edit scripts, but not write them from scratch.  jQuery is available, if needed.

Thanks for your help!

[mouseover GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02MSs.gif)  [mouseout GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rYVD.gif)  [original PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdZ0.png)

ETA: This is what I tried before, although this wasn't the final version of it since I was trying different things on that site that lets you try scripts on, and I think I had the timing set to 2888.  I don't have the other script since I didn't save it:

```
$(".as-panel[data-index='0']").mouseover(function() {
$(this).find("img").attr('src','/bouncing-balls.gif');


});

function pausecomp(millis)
{
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < millis);
}


$(".as-panel[data-index='0']").mouseout(function() {
  // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
    pausecomp(500);     
 $(this).find("img").attr('src','/bouncing-balls-reverse.gif');


});
```

Comment: Hi @CDV, could you provide some code of your last try. It would help us to help you.

Comment: Sure, I forgot I had the file saved still.  It was this one:

$(".as-panel[data-index='0']").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr('src','/bouncing-balls.gif');

    });

    function pausecomp(millis)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        var curDate = null;
        do { curDate = new Date(); }
        while(curDate-date < millis);
    }

    $(".as-panel[data-index='0']").mouseout(function() {
      // `this` is the DOM element that was clicked
        pausecomp(500);     
     $(this).find("img").attr('src','/bouncing-balls-reverse.gif');

    });

Comment: For reading ease, I will edit my original post....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed the animations to last about 3 seconds, but you can change that. Using `setTimeout` and a couple boolean values, we can delay the mouse on or off operation and queue up the next one. I also preload the images at the beginning to smooth out any loading flickers.

```js
const imgs = ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/02MSs.gif", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rYVD.gif", "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdZ0.png"];

imgs.forEach((img, i) => {
  this["image" + i] = new Image();
  this["image" + i].src = img;
})
let imgtimer, allclear = true,
  nextEvent = null
$('#imghover').mouseover(imgMo).mouseout(imgMo)

function imgMo(e) {
  if (!allclear) {
    if (!nextEvent) nextEvent = e
    else nextEvent = null
    return
  }

  $("#imghover").attr('src', e.type === "mouseover" ? imgs[0] : imgs[1]);
  allclear = false;
  imgTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    allclear = true;
    if (nextEvent) imgMo(nextEvent);
    nextEvent = null
  }, 3000)
}
```

```css
#mo {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

html {
  background: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='showimg'>
  <img id='imghover' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOdZ0.png' />
</div>

<!--
<div id='mo'> Mouse over and out on this text to see the image change</div>
-->
```

Comment: If you saw my previous comment that I deleted, ignore it!  I didn't realize the mouseover was connected to the text and not the images themselves!  *Facepalm*  My brain has been out of order all day today!  Anyway, YES!!!!!  The script is awesome on here, thank you so much!  I will go try it on my site now!  :-D

Comment: Great, if it works for you, please remember to accept this as the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Okay, it is sort of working, but it has issues that I can only figure some out about: 1. If you mouseover from the bottom and hover, the reverse GIF will play immediately, then play again (snapping the balls back to the bottom) upon mouseout, and occasionally then randomly the first GIF will replay, leaving the balls on the bottom.  It doesn't happen when mousing over from the other three sides!  2. If you mouseover then mouseout and mouseover again before the sequence is played, it will replay the reverse GIF upon mouseout.  3. The PNG doesn't appear at the end, but that's fine because I...

Comment: ...added a black background to the GIFs so everything looks as good as the PNG does.

Comment: Oh yeah, and Dreamweaver says there's a syntax error in "imgs.forEach((img, i) => {"  BTW, I am using the script as rolling over the image itself, not text, within a <p> tag.

Comment: Okay, I also just discovered that if you enter the mouseover on the top or left/right sides, hover until after the GIFs play out, and exit on the bottom (only happens to the bottom), the first GIF plays again, leaving the balls on the bottom.  I tried loading the latest jQuery (3.6.0.min) instead, but the problem persists.

Comment: @cdv - got it. I think I fixed all those issues. You can mouse on/off all day long and it will never play the wrong thing. Also I think dreamweaver didn't like the arrow function `() => {` I used for setTimeout, so I changed that. Give this a go and let me know. I put a border around the image just for testing the edges of the events, but you can easily remove that.

Comment: WOOHOO!!!!  It is perfect!!!!!!  Thank you SOOO much, Kinglish!  You definitely deserve your crown.  (Oh, and Dreamweaver still didn't like the imgs.forEach... line, but whatever, 'cause the script works.)

Comment: Well, adding jQuery 3.3.1 to my actual site prevented the home page billboard slide show from loading pics, but thankfully your script works just fine using the 1.8.3.min and ui.1.10.3.custom.min the page already uses (it is a shopping cart installation I'm using for the whole new site redesign - even if I knew php well, I'm not about to design my own shopping cart, LOL).  My redesigned site isn't live to the public yet, so I can't post it, and that might be against the rules anyway, but just know, I am incredibly grateful for you, King!

Comment: Yeah, we're barely using jQuery and it'd be easy to do this without it. So, the lower version is fine. Happy to help!

Comment: Sorry for the one more comment, but I just checked out your Web site, and I have to say, I love your sense of humor 'cause it matches mine!  The Beef Stroganoff at the end of your (very cool) typed-out script of what you do, plus the recipe page, etc. made me laugh.  I've implemented my humor on my new site, so once it is up, I might just drop you an e-mail.  And you definitely don't look middle-aged, IMO.  I'm 40 and don't consider myself middle-aged, and thankfully don't look my age.  Okay, have a nice night!  :-)

Comment: Okay, one more question on this: today, I tried to change the timer to 3500 just so there's a little bit longer of the balls being on the bottom if someone had already mousedout (mouseoutted?), but changing it to anything, even 10000 doesn't do anything to change it (yes, I emptied my cache and tried it in a new Incognito window).  Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the 3000 timer?  Or why else is it not working?  It isn't a big deal if it can't be changed, but I like to understand things, so I had to ask.  :-)

Comment: changing that timeout variable from `3000` to `10000` should change it. I just tried in the snippet here and you'd notice that change... which means something is not getting updated. When you do notice that it hasn't changed after youve changed the code, do a view source and verify that the code actually changed in your page.

Comment: I have it in an external .js file, so doing view source won't work.  I'll have to change it and then wait, or try it on someone else's computer tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: I finally got it to change.  I actually did check the file on the server, and realized that at least this time when I did it, I had uploaded it to the wrong place (my FTP program connected me to the home instead of public_html folder), but I am not sure about earlier tonight.  I still had to close the tab and delete the cache for it to work, but it now works.  I actually put it at 4000 and like that.